# Tensorflow program stuck in infinite training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the code from GAN tutorial on generating MNIST digits in tensorflow.

(Link here: https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/dcgan)

Currently, the program stucks in an infinite training loop. I set the training dataset to be only one image, and set epoch = 1. I inserted print statements in the loop. In the train() function, it only prints a and b, but doesn't print c, which means it's stuck in an infinite loop in the second for loop.

Here I load, shuffle, and batch the data (training dataset is only one image for testing purpose)

```
(train_images, train_labels), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5 # Normalize the images to [-1, 1]
train_images = train_images[0:1,:,:,:]
print(train_images.shape)

BUFFER_SIZE = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 1

# Batch and shuffle the data
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
print(train_dataset)
```

These are the functions that define generator and discriminator model, losses

```
def make_generator_model():
    ...
    return model

generator = make_generator_model()
noise = np.random.normal(size=(1, 100))
generated_image = generator.predict(noise)

def make_discriminator_model():
    ...
    return model

discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
decision = discriminator.predict(generated_image)

cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    ...
    return total_loss

def generator_loss(fake_output):
    return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)

generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
```

These are the training functions:

```
EPOCHS = 1
noise_dim = 100
seed = tf.random.normal([num_examples_to_generate, noise_dim])

def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)
      print(images.shape)
      real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
      fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

      gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
      disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))

def train(dataset, epochs):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        start = time.time()

        for image_batch in dataset: #stuck in an infinite loop
            print('a')
            train_step(image_batch)
            print('b')

        print('c')
        # Produce images for the GIF as we go
        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        generate_and_save_images(generator,epoch + 1,seed)
        print('d')

        # Save the model every 1 epochs
        if (epoch + 1) % 1 == 0:
            checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)

        print ('Time for epoch {} is {} sec'.format(epoch + 1, time.time()-start))

    # Generate after the final epoch
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    generate_and_save_images(generator,epochs,seed)

def generate_and_save_images(model, epoch, test_input):
  ...

train(train_dataset, EPOCHS)
```

Comment: You define `train_dataset`, but are iterating over `dataset`. Looks like there is a mismatch here. I would guess that you are running this in a notebook and are accidentally iterating over a much bigger `dataset` that is still floating around in the kernel.

Comment: The function's first argument is `dataset`. So `train(train_dataset, EPOCHS)` means I'm iterating over train_dataset in the function. `dataset` is just the name of the argument

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that. What I don't quite get: Does it print `a` and `b` just once (that would be very strange) or repeatedly?

Comment: It printed a and b repeatedly, and won't exit the second for loop to print c. So it's stuck in this infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It turns out I was using tensorflow 1.14, but the code is written in tensorflow 2.0. In tf 1.x, I would need an iterator to escape the infinite loop.

Comment: I did upgrade to TF 2.0 too, it still doesn't train.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the loop by hand otherwise it will run indefinitely. From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator):

```
for e in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', e)
    batches = 0
    for x_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32):
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
        batches += 1
        if batches >= len(x_train) / 32:  # break loop here
            # we need to break the loop by hand because
            # the generator loops indefinitely
            break
```